# Open Source Project Managment / Billing System

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for an Open Source (or at least free) project managment / billing system, nothing teribly fancy but the minimum requirements are along the lines of:

1. Free.
2. Allows me to add mulitple clients.
3. Allows me to track client payments (super basic here I have an accountant for the major stuff) and send automated reminders to pay.
4. Free

It doesn't have to be Open Source but thats always a plus so I can add any other features I decide I need.

Needs to run on windows. (although a server could be either windows(not iis)/*nix)

Comment: Anyone care to comment as to why they voted for a close?

Comment: Personal preference. This question is about the business of programming. Not the actual activity of programming. I know that I have a more narrow view of "Programming Related" than most people, but it is the view that I have so it is the one that I use. To be honest I doubt that it will get closed.

Comment: It's not a big deal to me weather it gets closed or not I just want to know why people don't like it for 2 reasons 1)So I don't do it again 2)I've spent 6 months building my rep, i'd like to take as little of a  hit as possible and a close is often followed by down-votes.

Comment: @Unkwntech - I can understand that some people will see this as 'Not Programming Related'.  It's more along the lines of, "How do I add a spelling correction to Microsoft Word" than, "How can I mimic closures in Java"

Comment: For what it is worth, I will rarely down vote anything that I vote to close. For me, a close vote is purely whether I think the question belongs on SO or not. Downvoting I reserve for questions that belong but are really crappily written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably doesn't exists (not as one product). If I was building them I would separate the two. If it's good for billing, it probably isn't good for PM. If it's good for PM, it probably isn't good for billing.

For the billing, spend $150.00 and buy QuickBooks. For the PM side, it really depends on what you think Project Management is. You could always use something like Gforge, or one of the many bug trackers out there for keeping track of tasks. The rest of it is planning and estimating.

Answer (score 0):

For billing you can have a look on JBilling at http://jbilling.com/ .

Answer (score -1):

Try [Open Office .Org's](http://why.openoffice.org/why_oem.html) Calc (Excel) program.

Comment: WOW, now thats not old school </sarcasm> It's a viable solution but I'd rather just write an app.